# Prove inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have some difficulties to show that $\int_0^1 u^2(x) dx \leq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 (u'(x))^2 dx$ for some $u \in \{u \in C([0;1]) \cap C^2((0;1)) | u(0)=u(1) = 0 \}$ . I tried to write $u(x) = \int_0^x u'(t)dt$ and then use Cauchy-Schwarz on it, so I obtain $u(x) \leq (\int_0^x (u'(t))^2 dt)^{1/2}$. Then $u(x)^2 \leq \int_0^x (u'(t))^2 dt$. Finally $\int_0^1 u^2(x) dx \leq \int_0^1 \int_0^x (u'(t))^2 dt dx$. I don't really see how to conclude. Maybe it's not the write way. Thank you

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166945/poincare-inequality-question

Comment: You have not used Cauchy-Schwarz correctly. $u'(t) = u'(t)\times 1$, so you should be getting the term corresponding to $1$ in the RHS of the CS application.

Answer (score 4):

$\int_0^{1}u(x)^{2}dx=\int_0^{1} (\int_0^{x} u'(t)dt)^{2}dx$ and $(\int_0^{x} u'(t)dt)^{2}\leq x\int_0^{x} u'(t)^{2}dt \leq x\int_0^{1} u'(t)^{2}dt$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1u^2(x)\,\mathrm d x&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^xu'(t)\,\mathrm d t\right)^2\,\mathrm d x\\
&\underset{C.S.}{\leq} \int_0^1x\int_0^x u'(t)^2\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d x\\
&\leq \int_0^1 x\int_0^1 u'(t)^2\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d x\\
&=\int_0^1 x\,\mathrm d x\cdot \int_0^1u'(t)^2\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u'(t)^2\,\mathrm d t.
\end{align*}